# Android DialogInterface Infinite loop

Tags: java, android

The following is a method from my android program and when called it is being sent into an infinite loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need the stacktrace to solve this, it might not being possible because it is around 30,000 lines long once this infinite loop starts.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Enter a Title:");
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
builder.setView(input);

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        inputtext = input.getText().toString();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
builder.show();

try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

ShoppingList list  = new ShoppingList(this.getFilesDir() + inputtext);

while(stop == 0) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter an item:");
    final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
    input2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input2);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            inputtext = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            stop = 1;
        }
    });
    builder2.show();

    try {
        list.addItem(inputtext);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason it gets into an infinite loop is because the `stop` variable you use in the while conditional is only updated inside an `OnClickListener`. What are you trying to accomplish with the loop?

Comment: In the code you provided you create an `AlertDialog.Builder` named `builder2` but immediately start using `builder` instead. Could this be the source of your problem?

Comment: Mike, I am trying to have one box open for a title, and then have boxes show up to add items to a list until they click the stop button on the box. If this is not a very good way of going about this, go you please offer some other solution.

Comment: Yeah, that might not be the best way, from a user experience perspective. You might consider opening a dialog with a multi-line EditText, and have the user enter the different items on separate lines.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that but the only thing is that I don't know how long the list is going to be.